# At the hands of

Tags: grammar, meaning

[Source](https://apnews.com/article/islamic-state-group-peter-kassig-terrorism-849e7ce764310fe38debd59d09721067)

> American hostage Peter Kassig was losing hope that he would survive his captivity **at the hands of the Islamic State group**.

---

English is my second language.
A native English speaker said that the boldfaced part modifies the whole previous statement. However I think that it's wrong.
She said

> the bolded phrase would seem to modify the rest of the sentence, that is, Kassig is losing hope of survival at the hands of the Islamic State group, as opposed to say at the hands of an orangutan. It is not a matter of in whose captivity (IS or orangutan) he is losing hope. It is a matter of losing the hope of survival being a captive of IS.

Does the boldfaced part modifies the whole previous statement or does it modifies "his captivity"?

Comment: How could it modify the whole statement?

Comment: It modifies "captivity".

Answer (score 0):

It describes the party holding him captive. So it directly modifies "captivity."

To the extent that the whole clause starting with "that" explains why he was losing hope, you might say that the subordinate clause **as a whole** modifies the main clause, but it is stretching things to say that any one phrase in the subordinate clause does what the clause does. Notice that you can omit "at the hands of ..." without greatly affecting the meaning of the sentence. Actually, I would find it even more hopeless to be at the mercy of an orangutan smart enough to keep me captive, but, as you say, prolonged captivity by anyone is enough to engender despair.